# send()/sendDelayed(): Cannot send message (inet::Packet)accident, it is currently contained/owned by (omnetpp::cDefaultList)

Tags: simulation, omnet++

i want the specific node stop at specific location, i use callRefreshDisplay() method but i don't send packet in this method and get error.

```
void VeinsInetSampleApplication::callRefreshDisplay()
{
    //EV<<"refreshing!!!!!!!!!"<<"\n";
    double pos1 = 128;
    double pos2 = 130;
       double pos3 = 103;
       double pos4 = 105;
       static simtime_t time;
       simtime_t Fulltime=0;


     if (getParentModule()->getIndex() == 0 ) {
       if(mobility->getCurrentPosition().x > pos1 && mobility->getCurrentPosition().x < pos2){
       if(mobility->getCurrentPosition().y > pos3 && mobility->getCurrentPosition().y < pos4){



                   //getParentModule()->getDisplayString().setTagArg("i", 1, "red");

                   auto payload = makeShared<VeinsInetSampleMessage>();
                   payload->setChunkLength(B(100));
                   payload->setRoadId(traciVehicle->getRoadId().c_str());
                   timestampPayload(payload);

                   auto packet = createPacket("accident");
                   //packet->insertAtBack(payload);
                   sendPacket(std::move(packet));

                   traciVehicle->setSpeed(0);



}
```

Comment: This error means that the owner of your packet and the current module are not the same. How are you calling your `callRefreshDisplay()` method?

Comment: i'm newer in omnet++, i have if the location is at x and y i stop the vehicle. how do it?